# Flexbox выравнивание блоков относительно друг друга

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Имеется следующая верстка:

```css
.items {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.item__row {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">Наименование</div>
    <div class="item__row">Ссылка на профиль</div>
    <div class="item__row">Всего доходов</div>
    <div class="item__row">Потраченная сумма</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-header">
    <div class="item__row">выфвыфвфывыфвфывыфвыфвыфвыфывфвыфвыфвыф</div>
    <div class="item__row">ВКонтакте</div>
    <div class="item__row">фыв</div>
    <div class="item__row">Расходов не зафиксировано</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">1</div>
    <div class="item__row">2</div>
    <div class="item__row">3</div>
    <div class="item__row">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">12312312</div>
    <div class="item__row">1412421 124124</div>
    <div class="item__row">142421 124421142412124</div>
    <div class="item__row">412</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">123</div>
    <div class="item__row">321</div>
    <div class="item__row">45</div>
    <div class="item__row">64</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ew3m6ryc/)

Текущий вид выглядит  [подобным образом](https://c2n.me/43Be5VU)

Поля не выровнены относительно друг друга.
Как их выровнять с помощью `flexbox`, чтобы поля были выровнены относительно друг друга?

Чтобы выглядело [вот так](https://c2n.me/43Be9Ab), не прибегая к медиа-запросам:

И чтобы не было вот  [таких вот](https://c2n.me/43BebXp) не состыковок.

Всем спасибо!

Comment: а что именно не получается? Правь вопрос, добавь стили...

Comment: Блоки относительно друг друга не выровнены, для удобства код разместил на jsfiddle и подкрепил скриншотами.

Comment: На последнем скриншоте, цифра 3 должна была выпасть вниз.

Answer (score 1):

> Поля не выровнены относительно друг друга. Как их выровнять с помощью flexbox, чтобы поля были выровнены относительно друг друга?
>
> И чтобы не было вот таких вот не состыковок

Задать базовый размер для элементов

> Чтобы выглядело вот так, не прибегая к медиа-запросам

Установить минимальную ширину

**Результат:**

```css
.items {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item-header {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.item__row {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 4 - 50px);
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">Наименование</div>
    <div class="item__row">Ссылка на профиль</div>
    <div class="item__row">Всего доходов</div>
    <div class="item__row">Потраченная сумма</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-header">
    <div class="item__row">Наименование широкое</div>
    <div class="item__row">Профиль указан на страницу ВКонтакте</div>
    <div class="item__row">Доходов не зафиксировано</div>
    <div class="item__row">Расходов не зафиксировано</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">1</div>
    <div class="item__row">2</div>
    <div class="item__row">3</div>
    <div class="item__row">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">12312312</div>
    <div class="item__row">1412421 124124</div>
    <div class="item__row">142421 124421142412124</div>
    <div class="item__row">412</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item__row">123</div>
    <div class="item__row">321</div>
    <div class="item__row">45</div>
    <div class="item__row">64</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Этот же пример на [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/MWgBPJZ) (если удобнее)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]